# How to refine faces associated to sharp edges in CGAL

Tags: c++, cgal

I have an edge map from `Polygon_mesh_processing::detect_sharp_edges` that selects the edges of a mesh. How could I get the range of faces associated with these edges so I can refine them?

I am looking for something like `Polygon_mesh_processing::connected_component`, but to get faces from edges.

Comment: Do you mean the faces that are incident to the sharp edges, or the whole connected components that contain at least one face incident to a sharp edge?

Comment: The first option, faces that are incident to the sharp edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care strictly about the faces incident to the the edges, you can do something like this:

```cpp
  [...]

  auto eif = get(CGAL::edge_is_feature, mesh);
  PMP::detect_sharp_edges(mesh, 90 /*angle*/, eif);

  std::vector<face_descriptor> faces_incident_to_sharp_edges;
  for(edge_descriptor e : edges(mesh))
  {
    if(!get(eif, e))
      continue; // edge is not sharp

    halfedge_descriptor h = halfedge(e, mesh);
    if(!is_border(h, mesh))
      faces_incident_to_sharp_edges.push_back(face(h, mesh));
    if(!is_border(opposite(h, mesh), mesh))
      faces_incident_to_sharp_edges.push_back(face(opposite(h, mesh), mesh));
  }
```

If you want faces that are at least sharing a vertex with a sharp edge, then you can look into `CGAL::halfedges_around_target()`.

Comment: It does exactly what I wanted, thanks!